# using rxjs and distinctUntilChanged to get items from api call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to learning rxjs operations and I am trying to use rxjs to get distinct items.

I am getting the following data from my api call

```
[0 … 99]
0: {option: "OptionOne", subOption: "subOption11"}
1: {option: "OptionOne", subOption: "subOption12"}
2: {option: "OptionTwo", subOption: "subOption21"}
3: {option: "OptionTwo", subOption: "subOption22"}
...
...
...
```

Api call

```
  getOptions(): Observable<Options> {
    const url = `https://localhost:5001/api/options/`;
    return this.http.get<Options>(url).pipe(map((item) => item));
  }
```

I am trying to get options and subOptions. I have setup the code the following way in my component.ts file

```
  getDistinctOptions(data: Options) {
    const source$ = from([data]);
    source$.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged('option')).subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

How can I loop through and get distinct options?

Comment: why does your API call `map(item => item)` - what does that do?

Comment: @MrkSef, maps the incoming data?

Comment: @JeffBenister map used to transform your data in your case it doesn't change anything basicaly your can just `return this.http.get<Options>(url)`
And what do you mean by distinct items ?

Comment: @Elmehdi, I have multiple Options (like optionOne, optiontwo, optionThree ) but I want them to return only once. If I have 100 records, but only 10 options (optionOne...optionTen), I want to return those ten options. And Thank you, I will change that in my code.

Comment: @JeffBenister so you want delete duplicates ?

Comment: @Elmehdi, no, just want to return the items (options) once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood things correctly and the call to `/api/options` returns an `Options` type that looks like this:

```
type Options = Array<{ option: string; subOption: string }>;
```

Then one way of doing it with RxJS would be:

```
getDistincOptions(): Observable<Options> {
  const url = `https://localhost:5001/api/options/`;
  return this.http.get<Options>(url).pipe(
    mergeMap(options => options),
    distinct(item => item.option),
    toArray()
  );
}
```

Or if you just want to return an Array of strings with the different options:

```
getDistincOptions(): Observable<string[]> {
  const url = `https://localhost:5001/api/options/`;
  return this.http.get<Options>(url).pipe(
    map(options => [...(
      new Set(options.map(
        item => item.option
      ))
    )])
  );
}
```

Comment: Josep, thank you for the answer. This was very very helpful !!

Comment: Would it be possible to get your help on the following question as well? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436003/how-to-filter-data-from-json-given-a-property-in-json-array-of-objects

Thanks in advance.